# Who is talking about Android.StackExchange.com?

Tags: discussion

We send a lot of people to other Android-related sites, presumably because the information there is richer, specialized, or more complete.

But who out there is talking about [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com)? Are we getting any love from the Android community?

Comment: As a mod on another site, I'm constantly frustrated that the mod tools will show you traffic per domain, but won't give you the exact URLs the traffic is coming from. So you can see that you got 2000 hits from domain XYZ, but you go there and you have no idea where your site was mentioned. I wish SE would add referring URLs to the mod analytics. /rant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Android Guys are](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/10/24/stack-exchange-provides-answer-to-your-android-questions/).

The screen shot is obviously from today, as are a good number of the sample questions they suggest. I just wish they'd sorted questions by votes to showcase our "best of" stuff.

Comment: Saw that they mentioned us too :)